# installing nodeJs version on a container, using NVM

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I have a docker container which has NVM installed by default. when I try to install any version of node, or running command `nvm ls-remote` it fails to connect to it's server every time.

the message is:

> Version '6.11.2' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.

this error occurs just in this network I am joining to.

it is my `/etc/resolve.conf` file content:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search SAD.UM.AC.IR

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

result of `docker network ls` command is:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
dc8cffbb2789        bridge              bridge              local               
5efb2b5fb44e        host                host                local               
8c19a2b28c14        none                null                local
```

It is just a network problem!! Is there any thing to solve this??

Comment: does `curl ipinfo.io` work in that container?

Comment: is this problem related to container?? `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipinfo.io; Unknown error` there is no problem with this container in other networks! @TarunLalwani

Comment: Yes, could be temporary or config. Delete and run container again

Comment: No, it does not work. @TarunLalwani

Comment: What network are you joining it to? And what is the output of `docker network inspect <network>`

Comment: it is my university network which has local and internet access. to have internet access we should login with our user and pass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154661/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-saeed-at).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a discussion with [@TarunLalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani), I find what is wrong in this case. The problem is that my container does not use my host machine internet, so it has no internet access. I use this command when I run the container:

> docker run -it -v somewhere/:/somewhere --net=host -p 8585:8585 --name test docker-image

`--net=host` added to command.